# appending http: for the local URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm constructing the URL dynamically pointing to local IP address in my action class, issue is its appending http: when i clicked on the link due to which page cannot able to load.
Below is the URL constructed:

```
<a file='#' onClick=window.open('//154.66.111.123/SD/SPRD/index.htm','_self') >Click Here </a>
```

The above URL works if i copy and paste the code and save as html file, it redirects and the window with specified URL is opened when i click. But the same if i run on the server, i'm using tomcat server its appending http: in front of the URL and getting "Network Error". Below is the URL opened when i run application from the server,appending http: which is giving the problem. If i remove http: from below URL,it works. Please suggest.

```
http://154.66.111.123/SD/SPRD/index.htm
```

Is their any other approach i can follow?

Comment: Have you tried `file://154.66.111.123/SD/SPRD/index.htm`

Comment: @j08691, Yes in IE it is working but in chrome below is the error message in console: "Not allowed to load local resource: file://154.66.111.123/SD/SPRD/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because you're mixing RFC's.

The `//1.2.3.4/path` convention for specifying [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) addresses isn't a web standard, nor is it cross-platform compatible. It's actually an older non-URI address standard that's a throwback to when computers communicated across tiny networks using ad-hoc protocols like IPX and NetBEUI.

Using `//server/path` URI convention in a web environment means in most cases "use the same protocol we're using now, but switch to this address." For example, if you're browsing HTTPS and click a link `<a href="//example.com/">` it'll open `https://example.com/`.

The reason entering `//server/path` in IE loads up a folder view is because IE knows it can't speak SMB so it switches over to Windows Explorer mode. Since that's not part of the duty of any other web browser, it doesn't work.

If you have a web browser that supports SMB browsing, which not many modern browsers support, with the exception of IE. You could try using the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) way of switching over to a new protocol, `smb://server/path` or more specifically `cifs://server/path`. Even these might not work unless the browser is configured with a special protocol handler. Remember, this is non web-standard functionality.

Sorry I can't be of more help, but I hope this is enlightening.